# Lumen Laravel - no me acepta request de archivos

Tags: laravel, archivo, fileupload, lumen

Estoy intentando guardar archivos utilizando Lumen para mi RestApi, actualmente tengo mi funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
public function generateTrainer(Request $request){
        return response()->json($request);
}
```

Estoy retornando como prueba, todo el `$request` para ver que parametros viajan

Realizando pruebas con PostMan me di cuenta que es problema de Lumen ya que estoy enviando correctamente mi archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, me retorna `"files"` vacio, alguien sabe si debo configurar algo en *Lumen* para que pueda aceptarme el envio de archivos? Ya intente agregar los headers:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

Aún asi no me deja. **¡Help!**

> Intento 2
>   He cambiado un poco mi código, y descubrí que el archivo es correctamente enviado:

```
$file = $request->file('files');
 if($file){
     return $file->getClientOriginalName(); // OK WORK!
  }
```

Pero si intento hacer una respuesta Json no sale como en la img de arriba.

```
$file = $request->file('files');
if(...){
  return response()->json('ok Work'); //JSON NO WORK
```

Comment: creo que sí se está subiendo pero no estás retornandolo de la manera correcta. prueba retornandolo así `return $request->file('files');` desde el controlador y te dará la ubicación temporal del archivo subido en el server

Comment: Lo mismo pense, más sin embargo colocandolo de la forma que me dices solo me manda `{}` ¿Qué demonios?

Comment: estas usando el método post, cierto? no se alcanza a ver en la imagen

Comment: Si así es, es metodo `post` de otra forma me arrojaria error de rutas.

Comment: pues no lo sé, estoy probando lo mismo y me devuelve el path temporal del archivo. Prueba con `if($request->hasFile('file')) { return [ 'name' => $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(),  'extension' => $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension() ]; } return 'no ha llegado ningún archivo';`. Quitando todos los headers que hayas agregado.

Comment: Pero estas trabajando con Lumen?

Comment: sí, con la versión 5.4, pero para este caso es lo mismo [doc](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files), [otros métodos](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5478a9d20d181e8d5a0ef532906e67b6d4d7bd79/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L64)

Comment: He agregado otros datos a mi pregunta, acerca de Json, puedes verlo?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sí se puede estar subiendo el archivo, pero no estás retornandolo de la manera correcta.
Prueba retornandolo así:

```
return $request->file('files');
```

desde el controlador y si llegó hasta ahí, te dará la ubicación temporal del archivo subido en el server.

También puedes probar con `if($request->hasFile('file'))`:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')) { 
    return [ 
        'name' => $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), 
        'extension' => $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension() 
    ]; 
} 

return 'no ha llegado ningún archivo';
```

Para lo que dices en el edit de la pregunta:

> Intento 2 He cambiado un poco mi código, y descubrí que el archivo es
>   correctamente enviado:
>
> ```
> $file = $request->file('files');
>  if($file){
>      return $file->getClientOriginalName(); // OK WORK!
>   }
> ```
>
> Pero si intento hacer una respuesta Json no sale como en la img de
>   arriba.
>
> ```
> $file = $request->file('files');
> if(...){
>   return response()->json('ok Work'); //JSON NO WORK
> ```

El método [`json()`](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses) establecerá automáticamente el encabezado `Content-Type` en `application/json`, así como también convertirá el array dado en JSON usando la función PHP `json_encode`.
Entonces debes pasarle un array para que `json()` lo codifique correctamente:

```
return response()->json([ 'message' => 'ok Work' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando uses postman y quieras mandar un archivo imagen así mándalo mediante un base 64 como texto, aqui puedes crear uno https://www.base64-image.de/ y lo colocas en el campo